# IOS smart app banner not showing on iphone 4, but works in iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

I am creating smart banner app some thing like below

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=...">
```

If I am accessing it from an iPhone 5s - Version 7.1.1, it displays the banner.

If I am accessing it from an iPhone 4, IOS 6.1.2, it does not display the banner. Simply the banner flashes and disappears. Even i cleared the cookies and given reset.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the region of the app-store on the 6.1 device. If the app is not available in the connected app-store the banner will get suppressed automatically because it's not available

Comment: Thanks Petesh for the comments. I have verified on 6.1 device and the app is available in the country. If we are searching for the app on the app store it displays it. Even we tried hitting the direct url of the app from the safari browser and it take us to the respective app on the app store. Any idea ? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: The only other reason for it flashing like that which I can think of is that it's not supported on the device in question. have you tried using the web inspector to debug the device while connected to your mac?

Comment: No I haven't tried web inspector to debug on mac. I tried it in chrome browser emulator and i was able to see the smart banner. As you said, I too suspect that the problem may be with respective device itself. Even I am facing this problem on android device too. The smart banner works on most of the android device except HTC One M8. Bit Strange !!